# Multi-Threading Server with shared Resource

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to make a simple game in Java. I want to code a server that accepts multiple players. Here is the meta of the game:

A player connects to the server to play a game, and indicate a number. Each player plays one game only. The game only starts or resolve if 4 players get connected. If the sum of all players number is greater than 21 all lose, else, all win. After the game resolves each player must be warned if it won or lost.

The algorithms for the win/lose check, or accept multiple clients I get it. My doubt is what should be a thread (or a runnable object) and/or what is a shared resource. Just a few guide lines and so I can implement this.

Comment: What did you try and what exactly didn't work the way you expected it to work?

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the way concurrency works. I could do this in a code-and-fix way, like a game be a runnable objects with a list of players and just start/be created when i have 4 players. After the game resolves, would be print to each client the result. But what i truly want is each client be a Thread that after input the number, stays blocked (await()) and when all players introduce their numbers, would be warned to continue and print the result.

Comment: You should avoid multithreading when you can. Multiple threads lead to deadlocks and race-conditions which result in obscure and impossible to reproduce bugs. Java provides [New-IO](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html) which is a way to handle a large number of clients in one thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have understood from your statement is that you need exact 4 players to decide game's outcome. each player passes a number while connecting to server and he/she is not allowed to enter or pass anything more.

so the shared resources are **TOTAL SUM** and **NUMBER OF CONNECTION** and thread is **connection to server**. So whenever a player requests to connect you, start a new thread and this thread increment the shared **TOTAL SUM** and **NUMBER OF CONNECTION** and after incrementing also check the value of total sum and no. of connection.

Comment: So, in the Game class (if it exists) how it should start ? To be more specific, how could i relate the player and the game ?

Comment: you can have a GAME class which implement runnable and it has all shared resource and run method. The constructor will take input as number and start this inner thread. The inner thread or run method will implement all game logic. There is another class CONNECTION that create and start GAME thread.